# Can Raspberry Pi 4 benefit from 3.5A power supply?

Tags: pi-4, power, usb-power

Experiencing external SSD data corruption issues which I believe are related to power issues.

Evaluating if it’s worth upgrading power supply from official Raspberry Pi 3A USB-C power supply to [Argon Forty](https://www.argon40.com/products/argon-one-type-c-power-supply?variant=39735277420609)’s 3.5A USB-C power supply.

Comment: What makes you think its power related? A powered usb hub might be a better solution if so. I use an official 3A psu on my Pi400 with SSD without issue.

Comment: The max USB capability is 1.2 A,  shared over all USB outlets, so if you are exceeding that, even momentarily, a beefier PSU won't fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are actually having power problems, and not problems with a poor quality or worn out SD card...

Power problems could be caused by:

- Poor quality power supply (not likely if it is an official Pi power supply and not damaged by surges or lightning)
- Over budget use of power by accessories (move them to a powered usb hub?)
- Inappropriate manual removal of power (stop that!  Shut down cleanly first)
- Accidental removal of power (maybe look into a Pi rated UPS?)
- Dirty input power (again...Pi UPS?)

A higher voltage will not fix any of the above problems.

Comment: *"A higher voltage will not fix any of the above problems."*  -> The OP is not asking about that, and of course the supply to the Pi must be ~5V anyway.  However: the supply is probably a good one in that it puts out 5.25V; at some point the Rpi official supply was bumped up to 5.1V I believe on the premise that this *can* mitigate against sudden voltage drops -- which is what can happen when you try to instantaneously pull an amount of current close to (or greater than) the supply's *amperage*.  Which greater amperage probably also mitigates against this.

Comment: ...So while you still won't be able to draw more than 1.2 amps over the USB, you may be able to do it *more consistently*, ie., without fluctuations caused by an electronic device's rapidly fluctuating needs.  A better solution might be better regulation, but Pis, being low cost devices, I think do not have the gold standard or anything there.

Comment: Actually, the 5.1v is more likely to mitigate extra long supply wires that are too thin and cause a voltage drop.  The regulator on the pi is at least good enough to fix the slightly higher voltage if there is no drop.

Answer (score 1):

A Pi 4 shouldn't consume more than say 500-800mA ([Reduce power consumption Raspberry PI 4](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/125011/reduce-power-consumption-raspberry-pi-4)) by itself, so I don't think your problem is with the power supply (unless of course it is a low quality one where voltages float around).

Corruption has other causes like for example [SD card corruption](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38344/sd-card-corruption)

Comment: Interesting that the top answer to "SD card corruption" is about "power problems"...  Probably the most common cause of filesystem corruption is unclean shutdowns, due to either ignorance, laziness, or *power problems*.

Comment: @goldilocks Power problems could happen if live somewhere with dirty power or frequent sudden outages or brown-outs.

Comment: Yes, those are definitely power problems...

Comment: Note that SD cards have a limited age measured in write cycles.

Comment: SSDs have exactly the same limitation.